# Mongoose Create operation(s) not working immediately after Delete operation(s)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to repopulate my collection on an API call using the data I receive. I basically want to wipe of the entire collection(s) and repopulate them with the new data I have received in my API call.

The creation operations work fine if I don't run the delete operations. However if I try running the delete operations first, no new documents are created.

Here is a stripped down version of my controller function:

```
let { data } = req.body
try {
    let result = await Record.deleteMany({});
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json('Unable to clean database');
}
for (let i in data) {
    await Record.create(data[i]);
}
return res.status(200).json('Successfully Processed CSV')
```

How do I go about resolving this? Basically all I want is to delete all documents within the collection and add the new documents immediately after.

Answer (score 0):

use `for of` if data is an array of objects you can do like this:

```
let { data } = req.body
for (let newRecord of data) {
    await Record.create(newRecord );
}
```